# Prevent a page to load on browser back navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

in my React app I have 3 pages say a, b, c.

1. I navigate from 'a' - 'b' - c(on form submits goes to) - 'b'.
2. Now I am on page 'b' and click browser back.
3. I am taken to page 'c' where I check a condition and if it fails I should be taken back to page 'b' and further pressing of back button to page 'a' as it was previous page to page 'b' as per app flow.
4. User should not be allowed to visit page 'c' again.
5. I have tried to do this with history.replace but its not replacing page 'c' entry from history stack and user keeps on navigating between page b and page c.

Please share any insights...

Comment: I think the interactions between "b" and "c" should be redirects, so a back navigation from either goes back to "a". If users backs out to "a" from "c" and tries to go forward again, "c" redirects to "b". User can now go back to "a" or go to "c" via "b". Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could do something like this

first you need to create custom route that validate your condition if blabla cannot visit page 'c';

```
import { Redirect, Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router';

const ValidateRoute = (props) => {
  const { component, children, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(routeProps) =>
        <place your condition here> ? (
          Component ? (
            <Component {...routeProps} />
          ) : (
            children
          )
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/',
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default ValidateRoute;
```

then wrap your C route with ValidateRoute

```
<ValidateRoute component={c component} path="c path"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useHistory .replace hook to redirect your user to an specific page if that is your case OR you can set a Guard for your routes "which I personally prefer this approach" .

I wanted to provide you a code sample but found a good example on the following website so just visit it.
https://blog.netcetera.com/how-to-create-guarded-routes-for-your-react-app-d2fe7c7b6122